# Can you extend ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, extend

Is it possible to make a child class that extends ArrayList? If so, how?

Comment: @Rakesh Juyal yes i did try and i faced some problem. So i was just making sure.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can extend any class that is not **final** in Java. Having said that, you should avoid inheritance if there is no **true is-a** relationship. Consider composition for reuse. Read about [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: You can extend any class that is not final in Java. But the class also needs to have at least one public constructor.

Answer (score 21):

Yes you can.

```
public class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E>
{
}
```

However, I'm not sure why you would want to do this.

Comment: to rename it something way more awesome than ArrayList, of course. -> List l = new MySuperAwesomeSandwichMakingConstantTimeLookupSwissArmyList();

Comment: Sorry for being super duper stupid, but what does the E mean?

Comment: @IchHabsDrauf When you create an ArrayList, you need to specify which type the list will hold. For example "new ArrayList<String>()". Thus E is a placeholder for the type (in this case it is String). This called a "generic type". If you create an instance of MyArrayList you will do it like this: new MyArrayList<String>(). This will pass the type "String" to the generic type of ArrayList and thus create a parent of ArrayList<String>.

Answer (score 10):

As many other have said, yes, you can extend class `ArrayList`, but it is not something that you should normally do; it is not considered good practice in Java.

I'm mainly a Java programmer, but the past months I've also been working on C# code. It seems like it's a common idiom in C# to extend the standard collection classes if you need a collection of a specific type (I actually don't know if it is a common idiom in general - at least the people who wrote the code I'm working with are doing this all the time).

So if they have a class `Person` and they need a list of persons, they'd create a class `PersonList` that extends the C# equivalent of `ArrayList<Person>`.

The common idiom in Java would just to use `ArrayList<Person>` if you need a list of `Person` objects and not to create a specific subclass for this.

I'd advise you to stick to the common Java way of doing things, and not create your own subclasses of `ArrayList` or other collection classes.

Comment: Hey there. Since you're suggesting not to override the class, how would I go about getting a callback, when an item is added to a list?

Comment: @Sipty For something like that, where you really want to add new functionality instead of just using it with a specific type argument (as in my description above), in my opinion it's legitimate to create a subclass.

Comment: @Sipty Overriding is an option, but imagine your college adds a different independent functionality, so you have `ExtList1 extends ArrayList` and  `ExtList2 extends ArrayList`. Now you want them both at once and you're out of luck. Or you need the same feature with a different base list implementation (maybe `LinkedList`, though it's virtually always wrong to use it). These are all cases when delegation wins. It needn't be more verbose when [someone has created the base already](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingList.html).

Answer (score 2):

ArrayList is not final class and it provides public constructor, so technically it can be extended.

But best practice is **delegate** rather than extend.
See: [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

Comment: Ummm ... it is **not** best practice to use delegation instead of inheritance **in all situations**.  You should make the decision on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 0):

Just try it out. The class is not final, it's constructor is public, so you can. However, it's probably no good idea for a beginner.

Most of the time, it's no good idea for anyone. Imagine you add some functionality and get `ExtList1 extends ArrayList`. A college of yours adds a different independent functionality, so you have `ExtList2 extends ArrayList`. Now you want them both at once and you're out of luck.

Or you need the same feature with a different base list implementation (maybe `LinkedList`, though it's virtually always wrong to use it). Again, out of luck.

These are all cases when delegation wins. It needn't be more verbose when [someone has created the base already](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingList.html).

---

I'd only inherit from `ArrayList`, if there was a very good reason for doing exactly this. Maybe some *really extreme* performance requirements based on proper JMH benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, extending java lang data structures is a very bad idea.
However, if you have some logic you want to isolate in a collection class, I would suggest bellow solution:

```
public class ProductCollection{

    ArrayList<Product> products;

    public Product getByCode(String code) {
       // ... your logic goes here.
    }
}
```