# How can I override the toString method of an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, overriding, tostring

I would like to have my own implementation of the toString() method for an ArrayList in Java. However, I can't get it working even though I added my toString() like this to the class that contains the ArrayList.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String result = "+";
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        result += " " + list.get(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

When I call my ArrayList like this `list.toString()`, I still get the default representation. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should do something like

```
public static String listToString(List<?> list) {
    String result = "+";
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        result += " " + list.get(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

and pass the list in as an argument of `listToString()`. You *can* technically extend `ArrayList` (either with an anonymous class or a concrete one) and implement `toString` yourself, but that seems unnecessary here.

Comment: You might also get a performance improvement by using `StringBuilder` instead of `String` here.

Answer (score 14):

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>()
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override public String toString()
    {
        return super.toString();
    }
};
```

Comment: The downside of this approach is that you must create an anonymous implementation that extends `ArrayList` every time you want/need this =\.

Comment: If you really need it one time, it wouldn't be really useful =\.

Answer (score 10):

You can't override the `toString` method of `ArrayList`<sup>1</sup>. Instead, you can use a utility class that converts an `ArrayList` to a `String` the way you want/need. Another alternative would be using `Arrays.deepToString(yourList.toArray())`.

Using Java 8, this can be done very easily:

```
//List<String> list
System.out.println(String.join(",", list));
```

Or if you have a `List<Whatever>`:

```
System.out.println(
    list.stream()
        .map(Whatever::getFieldX())
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
);
```

I'm still against extending `ArrayList` or similar, is technically possible but I don't see it as a good option.

---

<sup>1</sup> you could extend `ArrayList` and override the `toString` but generally that's not a great idea. Further info:

- [Extending a java ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8098615/1065197)
- [Can you extend ArrayList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4779173/1065197)
- [To extend ArrayList, or to not extend ArrayList](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2044491)

Comment: Is `ArrayList` final?  Can you not `extend ArrayList` and override `toString()`?

Answer (score 8):

You need to write a class extending from ArrayList:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyArrayList extends ArrayList {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = "+";
        for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {
            result += " " + this.get(i);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's good to follow the Java naming conventions even for small sample code as other users try to learn from it. Here: the class name should start with a capital letter. It would also be good to include the word "List" in the class name.

Comment: @Puce I started with a capital letter, but yes your right the classname wasn't the best i changed it

Comment: How do I fix the MyArrayList is not generic error. I did that by adding `public class MyArrayList<object> extends ArrayList<object>` but I had to add sth: suppressWarnings("hiding");

Answer (score 0):

To override toString() for ArrayList Integer array:

```
class MyArrayList extends ArrayList<Integer> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override public String toString(  ) {
        String output = "";
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < this.size(); i++ )
            output = Integer.toString( this.get( i ) );
        return output;
        }
    }

ArrayList<Integer> list = 
    new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList( 5, 4, 2, 9, 1, 7 ) );
System.out.print( "list = " + list );
```

will generate:  list = [5, 4, 2, 9, 1, 7]

Answer (score 0):

You can override the toString method in a new created class but you should make sure the created class extends ArrayList. Then, you can override toString method. This is based on IS relationship. The new created class is a type of ArrayList.

You can also create an ArrayList, which is based on the HAS relationship. In this case, you have to write another method to return String instead of override toString method.