# Double brackets in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created an `ArrayList` in Java:

```
List<String> listValuesFromMap = new ArrayList<String>();
```

which I fill with values using `entry.getValue()` method:

```
listValuesFromMap.add((String) entry.getValue().toString());
```

and I got something like this:

```
"names" : ["[name1, name2, name3]"]
```

How to remove these extra brackets with quotes to get only:

```
[name1, name2, name3]
```

Whole part of code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Map<String, Object> attributes = (Map<String, Object>) input
                        .getValueByField(ATTRIBUTES_FIELD);

Document mongoDoc= new Document();
List<String> listValuesFromMap = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : attributes.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().contains("names")) {

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            listValuesFromMap.add((String) entry.getValue().toString());

            for (String item : listValuesFromMap) {
                jsonArray.add(item.toString());
            }
            mongoDoc.put(entry.getKey(), jsonArray);
        }
        else {
            listValuesFromMap.add((String) entry.getValue().toString());
            mongoDoc.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
}
```

I think the problem is in the line `listValuesFromMap.add((String) entry.getValue().toString());` - values from the `entry.getValue()` are already in [] and `add` method put extra []. Does anyone know how to avoid these extra brackets?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I override the toString method of an ArrayList in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129505/how-can-i-override-the-tostring-method-of-an-arraylist-in-java)

Comment: I need a complete example to tell. Look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Could it be that the value from the map is itself a collection?

Comment: @OleV.V. the value from the map is also ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

I’m still unsure whether I know enough to answer. I’ll try.

As I understand, the double brackets come from having an `ArrayList` in an `ArrayList`. Which is fine for many purposes. However, to avoid the double brackets, you either need not to put an `ArrayList` into your `ArrayList`, or to take it out again before printing it (or what you need to do with it). For the first option, here’s how to add the elements of the `ArrayList` individually to `listValuesFromMap` rather than just adding the list:

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : attributes.entrySet()) {
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        if (entry.getKey().contains("names")) {

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            for (Object name : (ArrayList<?>) value) {
                listValuesFromMap.add(name.toString());
            }

            for (String item : listValuesFromMap) {
                jsonArray.add(item);
            }
            mongoDoc.put(entry.getKey(), jsonArray);
        } else {
            listValuesFromMap.add(value.toString());
            mongoDoc.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

You may also consider taking the items to put into `jsonArray` directly from `value` instead of from `listValuesForMap`; however, this will not include values added to the list in previous iterations of the outer `for` loop, so it may not be what you want.

For the second option, `listValuesFromMap.get(0)` will return the first element of the list, that is, the `ArrayList` that you put in there. However, I don’t think this is what you need here.