# Should You Extend ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of enums but I need to make sure that there is only one of a particular enumeral (or whatever it's called). Should I make a new class that extends ArrayList and checks the input? I've seen that maybe it's best not to ([Can you extend ArrayList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779173/can-you-extend-arraylist-in-java)) but I can't see a better way.

my enum

```
enum myEnum{
    SPECIAL,
    OTHER1,
    OTHER2,//etc
}
```

with ArrayList

```
List<myEnum> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(myEnum.SPECIAL);
list.add(myEnum.OTHER1);
list.add(myEnum.SPECIAL);//OH NO!!!
```

without ArrayList

```
class myList extends ArrayList<myEnum> {

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int i, Collection<? extends myEnum> clctn) {
        if(check()){
            super.addAll(i, clctn);
        }else{
            //do something or throw error;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends myEnum> clctn) {
        if(check()){
            super.addAll(clctn);
        }else{
            //do something or throw error;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int i, myEnum e) {
        if(check()){
            super.add(i, e);
        }else{
            //do something or throw error;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(myEnum e) {
        if(check()){
            return super.add(e);
        }else{
            //do something or throw error;
        }

    }

    boolean check(){
        //do stuff
    }
}

myList list = new myList();
list.add(myEnum.SPECIAL);
list.add(myEnum.OTHER1);
list.add(myEnum.SPECIAL);//something happens or error is thrown
```

Is there a better way or is this acceptable?

Comment: Pick a better data structure - one that handles uniqueness for you. Perhaps have a look at a Set ?

Comment: See the Effective Java section on _Prefer delegation to extension._  If you extend ArrayList, then you must behave like ArrayList, and this thing won't.

Comment: @SamOrozco Where would you get such an idea?  Nope, not true.

Comment: @BrianGoetz I read an article on hacker news yesterday. It must have had bad information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, you should not extend ArrayList.

As @John3136 notes in the comments, a `Set` is a collection that handles uniqueness for you. Java offers [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) which is a set specialized to work with enums effectively. When working with enums, use this rather than other implementations like `HashSet`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need a Set.

From java documentation:

> public interface Set extends Collection A collection that
>   contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of
>   elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null
>   element. As implied by its name, this interface models the
>   mathematical set abstraction.

HashSet is one of the implementing classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want unique elements, you want a `Set`.

If you want a List, you also want to be able to order the elements.

Behold the [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), which maintains both uniqueness and order:

```
Set<myEnum> myEnums = new LinkedHashSet<>();
myEnums.add(myEnum.SPECIAL);
myEnums.add(myEnum.OTHER1);
myEnums.add(myEnum.SPECIAL); // SPECIAL is (silently) not added
```

If order is not actually important, just use a `HashSet` or the `enum` optimised `EnumSet`.

Answer (score 0):

Use EnumSet instead:
[EnumSet API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html)